# Entity framework 6.0 Inserts two rows instead of one

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

After review the answers and comments:
My DB structure is

```
 1) TABLE BASE_ID ( ID int PK (IDENTITY(1,1))
 2) TABLE USERS (ID int PK, FK(BASE_ID.ID).. rest of fields)
 3) TABLE THREADS (ID int PK,(IDENTITY(1,1), UserID FK (BASE_ID.ID) )
 4) TABLE_POSTS (ID int PK,(IDENTITY(1,1), UserID FK(BASE_ID.ID), ThreadID FK(THREAD.ID) )
```

I need to insert new values in these tables in one transaction using EF(6.0)
I stuck that EF create two records in BASE_ID even if I do:

```
//Create new base entry
BASE_ID base = new BASE_ID();
//Create new User
USERS user = new USERS();
//Init fields
THREADS thread = new THREADS();
POSTS post = new POSTS();
post.Thread =thread;// linked property not (int ThreadID since don't yet know it
base.User = user; //linker property
base.Posts.Add(post); //also linked property
//base.Threads.Add(thread);//this was removed. But problem not solved.
oEntity.BASE_ID.Add(base);
oEntity.SaveChanges(); // And here i have already two new BASE_ID's
```

UPDATE:
DB after commit becomes:

```
Posts.UserID=n //Lets say 1
Threads.UserId=n,//same as above
Users.ID = n+1; // incremented so 2
```

I was trying to add in various combination, like

```
user.BASE_ID = base;
oEntity.USERS.Add(user);
oEntity.THREADS.Add(thread);
oEntity.POSTS.Add(post);
oEntity.SaveChanges(); // same result as above.
```

I am really stuck.
Question: How to force (or explain to) EF that I need only ONE BASE_ID used for all inserted entries in post thread and user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be helpful if you specify what version of EF you're using.

Comment: It is there initially "using EF(6.0)"

Comment: In the last 2 tables "UserID FK (BASE_ID.ID)"   So this is a column name UserID that points to BASE_ID.ID ?  Either is should be FK to USERS or it should be called BASE_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is making it double

```
base.Threads.Add(thread);
```

You already added it before with:

```
post.Thread =thread;
```

So it would just be:

```
 //Create new base entry
    BASE_ID base = new BASE_ID();

    POSTS post = new POSTS() {Thread = new THREADS()};
    base.Posts.Add(post);
    base.User = new USERS();

    oEntity.BASE_ID.Add(base);
    oEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework automatically keeps track of the related data, so when you add a new entity it's reference properties are tracked by EF (it's being marked as [`Added`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate#memberList) by the [`ObjectStateManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager)).

When you add a related entity, it's automatically being marked as added, so if you re-add it again it's added twice, so per your code, instead of adding each entity separately (I take it `oEntity` is your context), just add the central object, then set its reference properties (i.e. `base.User` etc.).

Comment: Its not actually answers question "How to avoid it?"

Comment: I've edited my answer. You're second part of the code actually re-adds the entities. You should remove it.

Comment: It is not second part of code, it is example that I was trying even various ways to do my stuff. so actual code is only upper block, probably I should remove second one if it  is confusing.

Comment: point is when you set the property with the reference you actually are adding it already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help.
Actually even initial code was fine.
The cause was AfterInsert trigger on USERS table which was adding entry to BASE_ID.
So I mark your comments as Answer and close the thread. 
Thanks again.